# Multiple Queries with Parse Cloud Code Using Promises

Tags: backbone.js, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have two questions:

1. Is the below example the right way to execute multiple Parse queries in a single Cloud Code function?
2. Is the below example going to provide all the data I'm querying with **one** HTTP request (when I call `logbookEntries`) and then count as **two** Parse requests on my account because it's two Parse queries?

Here's the code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("logbookEntries", function(request, response) {

  //::: Query 1 :::
  var firstQuery = new Parse.Query("Logbook");
  var returnData = []; 

  firstQuery.find().then(function(firstResults) {
    returnData[0] = firstResults; 

  }).then(function(result) {  

    //::: Query 2 :::
    var secondQuery = new Parse.Query("Logbook"); 
    secondQuery.find().then(function(secondResults))
    returnData[1] = secondResults; 

  }).then(function(result) {
    response.success(returnData);

  }, function(error) {
    response.error(error);

  });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. It's one way, though not quite correct.
2. Yes

Your code should really be:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("logbookEntries", function(request, response) {

//::: Query 1 :::
var firstQuery = new Parse.Query("Logbook");
var returnData = []; 

firstQuery.find().then(function(firstResults) {
   returnData[0] = firstResults; 

   var secondQuery = new Parse.Query("Logbook"); 
   return secondQuery.find();
}).then(function(result) {
   returnData[1] = result; 

   response.success(returnData);

}, function(error) {
   response.error(error);
});

});
```

Or, a better way to structure it would be:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("logbookEntries", function(request, response) {

var firstQuery = new Parse.Query("Logbook");
var secondQuery = new Parse.Query("Logbook");

var promises = [];
promises.push(firstQuery.find());
promises.push(secondQuery.find());

Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(result1, result2) {
   var returnData = [];
   returnData[1] = result1; 
   returnData[2] = result2; 

   response.success(returnData);

}, function(error) {
   response.error(error);
});

}
```

Comment: That second example is delightfully simple--thank you! I don't see the `wait` method in the Parse Promise docs (https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Promise.html) but I assume it means "don't send the response until both promises are fulfilled".

Comment: Sorry, typo, should be `when` https://parse.com/docs/js/api/symbols/Parse.Promise.html#.when

Answer (score 1):

Just to update Wain's structured code:
Promise.when returns array when supplied with an array, so the correct code would be

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function([result1, result2]) {
```

and since there is no need to repack the array, it would simply be

```
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(result) {
   response.success(result);
```

[See here](http://parseplatform.org/Parse-SDK-JS/api/v1.11.1/Parse.Promise.html#.when) for more info.